# Find all the different times 12:34:55 with regex

Tags: regex

I have a document with times like

12:44:21 hello

I would like to know the regex to find
all the different times with the hello
message and then replace with nothing.

I am working on libreoffice but i can copy to other program if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: `(([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] hello` pattern

Comment: Maybe `^(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(?::[0-5]\d){2} hello$`. Or a less specific version `^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d hello$`

Comment: [se] isn't for you to get people to do your work. You are supposed to try your best to figure it our yourself, and then come here for help when you are stuck. You haven't shown what you've tried and how it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution for `libreoffice` is the following:

You can use this regex pattern:

```
^[:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}[:space:]
```

Where:

```
^ - beginning of string
[:digit:] - any digit 0-9
{2} -  two chars
```

**libreoffice regex formula will looks like:**

```
=REGEX("12:44:21 hello";"^[:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}[:space:]";"")
```

Note: Please don't forget to replace `"12:44:21 hello"` in formula with link to cell.

[More info at libreoffice official site](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html)